# Disable text select for input in Cordova app

Tags: android, css, cordova

I'm trying to forbid copying password in Cordova app even if you press "show password". I cannot find a solution. Here's what I tried so far.

```
.password {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

I've tested my app on Samsung S9.

Comment: did you apply password class to your password inputs?

Answer (score 0):

[There are some known issues with `user-select`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none). It is possible your device is one that has those issues. Some browsers implement this spec in a slightly different way.

You may want to try to resolve this using javascript if you want to be sure that you will have a consistent experience, since you are using a Cordova application.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$('input').bind('copy paste', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

if copying should be prevented too, also:

```
$('input').bind('copy', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

This is Jquery and should solve your problem.